# Resolve with QueryParams

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

How to use QueryParams with resolve:

1.Need to implement 'search' by passing queryParams (using parameters which are set) through route(from carSearch Component) 
**(exg: /cars?companyName='skoda'&launchYear="2018"&pageSize=10&pageNo="1")**.
2.Need to resolve the search function and show the fetched data in other component (carList Component).

Code which i tried:

SearchCar component:

```
  searchCars() {
   const options = {
     pageNo: this.pageNo,
     pageSize: this.pageSize,
     companyName: this.companyName,
     launchYear: this.year
   }

   this.userService.searchbycategory(options);

   this.router.navigate(['/cars'], {
      queryParams: {
      pageNo: this.pageNo,
      pageSize: this.pageSize,
      companyName: this.companyName,
      launchYear: this.year
    }
   });
  }
```

CarListResolver service:

```
   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
      console.log('Resolve CarList working');
      return this.userService.carListData;
     }
```

carList Component:

```
   ngOnInit() {
     this.route.data.subscribe((data: { filteredCars: any }) => {
     console.log(data.filteredCars);
      for (let car of data.filteredCars) {
         this.carList.push(car);
      }
     });
    }
```

User Service:

```
   carListSub: Subject<any>;
   carListData: Observable<any>;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {       
      this.carListSub = new Subject();
      this.carListData = this.jobListSub.asObservable();
    }

   searchCars(options) {
         console.log(options);
         const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
               'pageSize': JSON.stringify(options.pageSize),
               'pageNumber': JSON.stringify(options.pageNumber),
               'companyName': options.companyName,
               'launchYear': options.year
            })
        };
        return this.http.get(`/api/user/getsearchedCars`, httpOptions).pipe(
            map((res: ApiResponse) => {
               return res.data;
            })
        ).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.carListSub.next(data);
             }
        );
     }
```

I'm using : Subject and Observable in the service as i have to even add some more for search 
 from carList component and recall the same api.

Please help me to solve the above issue and correct me if i'am doing someting wrong.

Thanks in advance.